# Switch active screen/HTML file in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that has two completely distinct screens (with two different HTML files) that the user can switch between with buttons on each screen. Looking through the Chrome Extension references, the only way I could find to do this was with chrome.action.setPopup().

```
var switchButton = document.getElementById('screen2');
translateButton.addEventListener("click", updateScreen);
function updateScreen() {
    chrome.action.setPopup({popup: 'screen2.html'});
}
```

I have the above code in each of the javascript files that have the scripts for each screen. With this, the active screen switches, but only when the extension is closed (like clicked out of) and re-opened. I'd like it to just update instantly, without the user needing to re-open the extension.

Comment: Simply use the standard `location.href = 'screen2.html'`